# How to check the version of pyenv itself

Tags: python, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

The version of pyenv is listed in [Version History](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), how can I check the version of pyenv itself with a command? I searched for it, but couldn't find it.

Comment: `pyenv -v` or `pyenv --version`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was a rudimentary thing. Would you please post as an answer? I approve it.

Comment: posted the same with slight changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either `pyenv -v` or `pyenv --version` to get the version of `pyenv` itself.

```
% pyenv --version
pyenv 2.0.1
% pyenv -v
pyenv 2.0.1
```

When in doubt do `pyenv -h`

```
% pyenv -h
Usage: pyenv <command> [<args>]

Some useful pyenv commands are:
   --version   Display the version of pyenv
```

Version comes up as the first command.

Answer (score -1):

```
$pyenv version
miniconda3-3.16.0 (set by /Volumes/treauredata/.python-version)
```

Comment: This gives the version of the current python, not the pyenv version